# Issues with Docker networking on a GCP instance

Tags: docker, networking, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose

I'm trying to build and run a simple Docker container (using docker-compose to do this) on a GCP Instance (Ubuntu 20.04), and it seems that the container cannot access the internet, unless I run it using

```
docker run --net=host [...]
```

or use in my `docker-compose.yml` something like:

```
service:
  build:
    ...
    network: host
  network_mode: host
  ...
```

I'm wondering why it is so, that a simple docker container on a standard GCP instance with Ubuntu 20.04 should require some specific configuration to access Internet, and why I see almost no mention of this while searching for this issue on the web.

Am I doing something wrong, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you can only connect to the internet in host network mode I think there is something unusual on the network level. I once had a similar problem where we couldn't connect to the internet from inside a container. We could access the internet on the host VM (e.g. with curl), but not from inside the Docker container running on the same instance. Once we used the host network mode the problem was gone. But as far as I remember the problem turned out to be that we did not access the internet directly, but over a Cloud VPN tunnel which did not align with the MTU settings of the Docker daemon.

Answer (score 1):

See [Container networking](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/) for Docker and the principle is applied consistently across other container runtimes too.

Using `--net=host` or `network_mode: host` binds container(s) to the host's network.

Rather than broadly publishing all of a container's or service's ports to the host network (and thus making them host public), you can be more precise using `--publish=[HOST-PORT]:[CONTAINER-PORT]` or `ports` to expose container ports as host ports (and potentially remap these too).

One (of several advantages) to the not-published-by-default behavior is that you must take a second step to publish a container's ports to a host where there is increased possibility that the service may be accessed (via its ports) by undesired actors.

Comment: Thanks, the issue is not that I cannot publish ports, is that the container itself cannot access DNS (eg ping google.com doesn't work, although ping 8.8.8.8 works)